# What is Regex Expression which allow to me only alphabets, special characters and space?

Tags: c#

What is Regex Expression which allow to me only alphabets, special characters and space ???

This is my current one which does not work:

```
Regex r1 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z~@#$^*()_+=[]{}|\\,.?: -]*$");
```

Comment: What `special characters` you want to include?

Comment: all special characters I want to include..

Comment: @un-lucky your expression and your link is about `javascript`, not `c#`

Comment: Not very clear. So you want every chars except digit char?

Comment: Yes, do not include digit

Comment: What ave you tried already and what does it return?

Comment: Regex r1 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z~@#$^*()_+=[]{}|\\,.?: -]*$"); 
I try to this but not work

Answer (score 0):

Let `inputStr` be the input string that is a combination of letters digits and special characters.

ie.,

```
string inputStr="asdfsf$@#%# @$%#$^%$^412545SDF S4658#$%3453453$%#$53"
```

You will get the digits free string by using the following code:

```
string result= Regex.Replace(inputStr,@"\d", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any digit from your string:

```
string pattern = @"\d";
string str = "sjfk jsdkj f236470924824$^^*)()";
string output = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
sjfk jsdkj f$^^*)()
```

This will return you list of string split by digit, not include digit:

```
string pattern2 = @"([^\d]+)";
MatchCollection ms= Regex.Matches(str, pattern2, RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach(Match m in ms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
sjfk jsdkj f
$^^*)()
```

This will return you list of string split by digit, include digit:

```
string pattern3 = @"([^\d]+)";
string[] strs= Regex.Split(str, pattern3, RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (string s in strs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
sjfk jsdkj f
236470924824
$^^*)()
```